# MPAndroidChart Showing the values in X-axis

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I currently have 30 values in my line chart and currently the X axis is showing 01, 03, 05, 06.

How would i make it to show the X-Axis Like 01,02,03,04,05 with proper spacing between each x-axis

I'm currently using this method

```
float minXRange = 10;
float maxXRange = 10;
lineChart.setVisibleXRange(minXRange, maxXRange);
```

to show the values i want in my linechart

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. You can try this. This will set the X-Axis values of the graph.

```
final String[] values = {"01", "02", "03"};
        mChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                return values[(int)value];
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the granularity of the x-axis to 1f by doing getXAxis.setGranularity(1f)